# JQuery attribute Selector With ID and Class Selector

Tags: jquery, class, attributes, selector, html-table

I have a table with class "report-standard-alternatingrowcolors" and element_id is the id of tr element. At the end of selector I want to select td element with attribute selector. ".data" is the class of td element. But didn't work. It selects all td values. Do you have any idea?

```
alert($('.report-standard-alternatingrowcolors #element_id .data[headers="STATE"]').val());
```

You can check from :
http://jsfiddle.net/BscPP/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example has a few problems.

You had MooTools loaded instead of jQuery.

Your HTML was wrong.

```
<table class=""report-standard-alternatingrowcolors>
```

You need to put the class in the quotes

```
<table class="report-standard-alternatingrowcolors">
```

`<td>`s don't have a `value` attribute, so `.val()` is the wrong method, try `.text()` instead.

Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/BscPP/2/

P.S. If you want to add custom attributes to elements, you should prepend them with `data-`:

```
<td class="data" data-headers="STATE">123</td>
```

Then change the selector to:

```
$('.report-standard-alternatingrowcolors #element_id .data[data-headers="STATE"]')
```

New demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BscPP/3/

Note: IDs are supposed to be unique, so the `.report-standard-alternatingrowcolors` is a little extraneous.

```
$('#element_id .data[data-headers="STATE"]')
```

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/BscPP/1/

Here ya go.  You didn't have the main `report-standard...` inside of the quotes so that wasn't going to work.  Also you are putting way to much into the selector.  In the example provided all that was needed was to use the `.data[headers="STATE"]` and use the `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Comment: In his example, yes.  But in his real code, he may have more elements that match `.data[headers="STATE"]`.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it.  In your jsFiddle just change `.val()` to `.text()` and it works. A td element has no value.

Also, in the fiddle your class `"report-standard-alternatingrowcolors"` is not positioned correctly, it's outside the `" "`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#element_id td.data[headers="STATE"]', '.report-standard-alternatingrowcolors').text()
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/BscPP/5/)